# Incorrect output fscanf()

Tags: c

hello am trying to read a file with the code i wrote

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int task_id=0;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("output","r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {   
        printf("failed opening file");
        return 1;
    }
    else{
    fscanf(fp,"conhost.exe                   %d",&task_id);
    fclose(fp);
    printf("taskID is: %d",task_id);
    return 0;
    }
}
```

content of file for reference

```
conhost.exe                   4272 Console                    2     13,504 K
```

and i keep getting the output as 0

Comment: What does `fscanf` return?

Comment: What happens if you check the return value from `fscanf`?  I bet it returns 0 and you haven't read any values.

Comment: are you sure your `output` file contains exactly `conhost.exe           ...SPACES...        
   NUMBER`?

Comment: How many spaces are there supposed to be? What if someone miscounted?

Comment: @TimRandall I believe a single space in format string should consume them all.

Comment: Can't reproduce, but a better way to skip the first part would be with `int res = fscanf(fp,"%*s%d", &task_id);` which scans a string until the first whitespace but does not store it, and then reads the `int`.

Comment: The "space" is not even needed. `"conhost.exe (many spaces) %d"`,  `"conhost.exe %d"`, `"conhost.exe%d"` perform the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to get the '2' from your sample `output` file, you could do it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int task_id = 0;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("output", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {   
        printf("failed opening file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        fscanf(fp, "%*s%*d%*s%d", &task_id);
        printf("taskID is: %d\n", task_id);
    }   // Code
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that `fscanf()` lets you discard data by adding an asterisk between the format specifier and the percent sign - so you can amend this statement `fscanf(fp, "%*s%*d%*s%d", &task_id);` to collect the required data.

Answer (score 3):

Well you have a good answer by Mr. Cara (who I commend for using the *assignment suppression operator*), but I would add one more suggestion. Any time you are reading lines on input -- use a *line-oriented* input function like `fgets` that will help you avoid a whole host of pitfall with the `scanf` family of functions. You can then use `sscanf` to parse the wanted information from the buffer holding the line of data. This ensures what remains in you input stream doesn't depend on the *format-specifier* used.

Also, don't hardcode filenames -- that is what program arguments are for. A short example would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 1024u  /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {  /* don't hardcode name, use arguments */

    int task_id = 0;
    char buf[MAXC];
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }

    if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {   /* read with line-oriented function */
        fputs ("error: EOF encountered on file read.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    /* parse information with sscanf (read/discard initial string) */
    if (sscanf (buf, "%*s %d", &task_id) != 1) {
        fputs ("error: invalid file format.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("taskID is: %d\n",task_id);  /* output task_id */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/rd_task_id <output
taskID is: 4272
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: A more complete answer - upvoted